# Lenovo Yoga 2 not connecting to Zyxel Wi-Fi modem at all

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, router, lenovo-yoga

When I try to connect my **Lenovo Yoga 2** tablet to my **Zyxel VMG3625-T50B** WiFi modem and enter the password, it keeps showing "Saved" without actually connecting at all.

I think it is a problem specific to the connection of this tablet to this WiFi as the tablet works with other Wifi and the WiFi works with other devices.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: Your tablet is pretty old (released with Android 4.4?) and the Wifi router new, most likely it has a Wifi feature activated the tablet doesn't support. Check the Wifi settings in the router, disable some features like large channels, advanced management and/or WPA3 and check if your tablet can connect.

Comment: I tried disabling security and It worked Alhamdulilah so what should I do to make it work with security enabled ?

Comment: WPA2 with AES should be supported, activate that. WPA2 is old enough to be supported by any Android device. It has some problems regarding denial-of-service attacks as management frames are not encrypted, but the transmitted data is still secure.

Comment: I tried WPA2-PSK with AES whoch there is no option except that may work . The other option is WPA3 .   but It didn't work with it . There is also a Timer option under the encryption option so could it be the one who causes the problem !